# Using Regexp in Java to remove some text

Tags: java, regex

It is maybe a simple question. But I tried a lot of Regexp combinations and still not worinkg. My problem is: I have words like: **Test=move** or **Testing=move** 
I would like to remove the text 'Test=' or 'Testing='. In other words i need only the 'move' text after the '='. What is the best way to do that in Java? Thanks.

Comment: `string.replaceAll("Test(?:ing)?=", "");`

Comment: `But I tried a lot of Regexp combinations and still not worinkg.` , show your attempts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that for this problem, the `split(string regex)` is better suited:

```
String str = "Test=move";
System.out.println(str.split("=")[1]);
```

Comment: I tried you solution, and it solve my problem. I tried something like \w-\.\d worked not my code. thanks

Comment: @mesut: In this case, since you need to take part of the string after a given delimiter, the `split()` will yield cleaner code which does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace `\w+=` with `""` - this will get rid of any work preceding an equals sign.

```
myString.replaceAll("\w+=", "");
```

If the string before the equals sign has more than just letters you can add them to an optional selection:

```
myString.replaceAll("[\w-\.\d]+=", "");
```

This will remove any word with letters, numbers, hyphens and periods.